# Excel VBA error 2042 vlookup - how to handle this error

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have a user form with input data (Fullname, Field1, Field2, etc.) that I need to write to the table (column1 - Fullname, column2 - Field1, column3 - Field2) on the sheet.
Before writing, I need to check if the data that I have in user form are already in the table or aren't. If the data are in the table then I need to show msgbox with the text "Data are already written, do you want to overwrite?" if yes then overwrite data in a row according to Fullname that is the same in user form and table in column1

For checking, I use vlookup for Fullname, Field1, and Field2. But when I start first row of Vlookup code for fullname, code is ok but the second shows error 2042. Code is the same but results are not. I don't know how to handle error 2042 (no data match, even the data in userform and data in table are the same)

Can you help me?

Code is here

```
Dim Fullname As String                         
Fullname = AddEmployee_UF.TextBox1.Value

Dim Field1 As String                      
Field1 = AddEmployee_UF.TextBox2.Value

Dim Field2 As String                      
Field2 = AddEmployee_UF.TextBox2.Value


Dim check As Integer
Dim Sheet As Worksheet: Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Zaměstnanci")
Dim Applic As Application: Set Applic = Application
Set TableZaměstnanci = wshZaměstnanci.ListObjects("tblZaměstnanci")
Set Table = Sheet.Range("A2:Z100")
Dim lRowZaměstnanci As Object: Set lRowZaměstnanci = TableZaměstnanci.ListRows.Add

check1 = Applic.Vlookup(Fullname, Table, 1)
check2 = Applic.Vlookup(Filed1, Table, 3)
check3 = Applic.Vlookup(Field2, Table, 4)


If Err.Number > 0 Then
check = 1
Else
check = 0
End If


If check = 0 Then

With lRowZaměstnanci
.Range(1) = Fullname
.Range(2) = Field1
.Range(3) = Field2
End With


Dim yesno1 As Integer
yesno1 = MsgBox("Writing done succesfully")
If yesno1 = vbYes Then
Unload Userform
Userform.Show
Else
Unload Userform
End If

Else

Dim yesno2 As Integer
yesno2 = MsgBox("Data are already in table." & vbNewLine & "Do you want to overwrite?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Overwrite?")
If yesno2 = vbYes Then


With lRowZaměstnanci
.Range(1) = Fullname
.Range(2) = Field1
.Range(3) = Field2
End With
Else
Unload Userform
End If


End If
```

Comment: Use `IsError`??

Comment: I edited my question, i didnt say that i have the same data in userform and in table ( `vlookup(Field1, Table, 3`). For Fullname it works, but for Field1 not. Its not about checking if there is error or not, I need to work off the error 2042 (cause physicaly there is match, but vba says that isnt. :D ) If you understand me :D sry for maybe bad english

Comment: Error 2042 means that `Vlookup` did not find `Field1` in the leftmost column of `Table`.

Comment: I know but in `Table` is the same value as value in `Field1`

Comment: If you get an error, then it's not actually the same.